# Display List in a View MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, model-view-controller

I'm trying to display the list I made in my view but keep getting : "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Standings.Models.Teams]'."

My Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    Teams tm = new Teams();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = tm.Name.ToList();

        model.Add("Manchester United");
        model.Add("Chelsea");
        model.Add("Manchester City");
        model.Add("Arsenal");
        model.Add("Liverpool");
        model.Add("Tottenham");

        return View(model);
    }
```

My model:

```
public class Teams
{
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public string HomeGround {get; set;}
    public string NickName {get; set;}
    public int Founded { get; set; }

    public List<string> Name = new List<string>();
}
```

My view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Standings.Models.Teams>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Standings";
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        @item.Name
        <hr />
    </div>
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Do you want to pass a collection of teams or a list of team names (which is what you are passing)?

Comment: Why is a football team object named `Teams` (plural) and why does one team have multiple names? I think you need to look carefully at you model!

Comment: Try my answer below. Your model is not implemented correclty.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your action method considers model type as`List<string>`. But, in your view you are waiting for `IEnumerable<Standings.Models.Teams>`.
You can solve this problem with changing the model in your view to `List<string>`.

But, the best approach would be to return `IEnumerable<Standings.Models.Teams>` as a model from your action method. Then you haven't to change model type in your view.

***But***, in my opinion your models are not correctly implemented. I suggest you to change it as:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public string HomeGround {get; set;}
    public string NickName {get; set;}
    public int Founded { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you must change your action method as:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new List<Team>();

    model.Add(new Team { Name = "MU"});
    model.Add(new Team { Name = "Chelsea"});
    ...

    return View(model);
}
```

And, your view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Standings.Models.Team>

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Standings";
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        @item.Name
        <hr />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: It would need to be `model.Add(new Team() { Name = new List<string>() {"Manchester United" }});` (`Name` is a collection)

Comment: @StephenMuecke OP's models are little bit out of standart. Thanks, i have updated.

Comment: OP model makes no sense at all :)  I assume `Name` should be typeof `string` not `List<string>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Totally agree, so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong mode to you view. Your view is looking for `@model IEnumerable<Standings.Models.Teams>` and you are passing `var model = tm.Name.ToList();` name list. You have to pass list of **Teams**.

You have to pass following model

```
var model = new List<Teams>();

model.Add(new Teams { Name =  new List<string>(){"Sky","ABC"}});
model.Add(new Teams { Name =  new List<string>(){"John","XYZ"} });
return View(model);
```