# Outputting Object List to Verify Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make a collection of objects, in this case "AuditPoint" and I want to verify that the list contains the objects I expect it to.  I've tried the standard

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item)</p>
}
```

that is normally recommended for this situation but I couldn't get it to display my list. I would really like to double check the contents of my list because I'm picking up this project after my predecessor so I'm lost on a lot of the logic behind his code.  So outputting as much as possible to see what I'm doing is always nice but is sometimes difficult due to the intricacy of his program I find it difficult to connect my C# logic to the web logic (which includes html, javascript, typescript, jquery, mustache and I'm sure many other frameworks I have yet to find).

Below is where I am making my collection which I assume is being done right but if you can see anything obviously wrong please point it out.  I thought I would include this because it help with anyone's solution.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/auditpoints")]
public void Post([FromBody]AuditPoint auditPoint)
{
    AuditPoints auditPoints = new AuditPoints();
    auditPoints.Add(auditPoint);
    auditPoints.Save();
    //These are my additions below
    List<AuditPoint> autoPoints = new List<AuditPoint>();
    if (auditPoint.Automated == true)
    {
        autoPoints.Add(auditPoint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you missing m => item.PROPERTY?

Comment: @Biscuits when I add the dot after item intellisense doesn't come back with anything so maybe I am doing something wrong with the standard approach.

Comment: Maybe follow an ASP.NET MVC tutorial to learn more from a basic working example

Comment: @Biscuits I've been through those but unless I'm missing something I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You're creating a `List<AuditPoint>` and adding one item to it, but not returning it. In order for your view to display something the method needs to return it.

Comment: @ScottHannen it's not letting me `return View(autoPoints);`, specifically the `View();` part

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not letting me"?

Comment: @ScottHannen the intellisense doesn't bring up _View_ so then when I force type it I get "The name 'View' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Is this a Web API controller or an MVC controller? Does your controller inherit from System.Web.Http.ApiController or System.Web.Mvc.Controller?

Comment: @ScottHannen It is a Web API Controller (I've never used those before, usually stick to MVC)

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Web API controllers return models, not views. And without some additional configuration they typically wouldn't use Razor (cshtml) templates either.

Comment: @ScottHannen so I'll look into returning collections with Web API Controllers then.  We'll see how that goes

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
List<AuditPoint> autoPoints = new List<AuditPoint>();

 [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/auditpoints")]
    public void Post([FromBody]AuditPoint auditPoint)
    {
        AuditPoints auditPoints = new AuditPoints();
        auditPoints.Add(auditPoint);
        auditPoints.Save();

        ListAutoPoints(auditPoint);
    }

    public void ListAutoPoints(AuditPoint _autoPoint) {

                if (auditPoint.Automated == true)
        {
            autoPoints.Add(auditPoint);
        }


    }
```

I think the listing of the items need be separate from the Post logic, then called into existing or new Post method in the controller.

Also, I think, the model needs to be used to populate the list...

```
@Model IEnumerable<namespace.Models.AutoPoint>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
     <ul>
       <li>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AutoPoint)</li>
     </ul>            
    </div>
}
```

Model should fit something like this,

```
[Table("AuditPoints")
public class AuditPoint
{
   [Key]
   public AuditPointID { get; set;}
   public List<AutoPoint> AutoPoints { get; set;}

} 

public class AutoPoint
{
   public AutoPointID { get; set; }
   public Name { get; set; }
}
```

Similar answer here: [Display List in a View MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958119/display-list-in-a-view-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a direct answer to the question I posted here but I did solve the problem that this question was related to on my project so I am no longer seeking an answer.