# Compiler Error Message: CS1061 when trying to display uploaded images in a table

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to display images in a table but I keep getting the error in the title.

So far I have created the functions for uploading images to a website, and displaying them one by one in a separate page for each. This works fine. I also want to create a page where all the images are displayed in a table, and this is my problem. When I use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Picture)
```

I get the path for the picture printed on the screen. However, when I try to display the images using

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.Picture)" height="500" width="500" />
```

exactly as I have done when I was displaying each picture in a separate page - it doesn't work any longer and I get the error message in the title. The full error message is as follows:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Picture' and no extension method 'Picture' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What is the problem? The only difference I see is that for the table view I am using IEnumerable (it was automatically generated at some point, I've been following a lot of tutorials), perhaps that is where the problem lies?

Comment: please review this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958119/display-list-in-a-view-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that your `Model` is of type `IEnumerable` and `IEnumeerable` does not contain a property named `Picture`. You may want to display `Picture` property of its each item, something like:

```
@foreach(var x in Model)
{
    <img src="@Url.Content(x.Picture)" height="500" width="500" /> 
}
```