# Display Sql Function to a list

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-function

> Hi,
>
> I have a function which return a table and i wanted to display this
> table in a list - note: the function is executed successfully.
>
> My Function

```
   ALTER function [dbo].[VLOUL]
    (
    @LID int
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    As
    Return
    
    Select Users.UserName,Product.PName,Users.SK,Users.Brand,Users.CN,Users.SN,Users.AT,Users.Ref,Users.DC
    from Users 
    INNER JOIN Product ON Product.PID = Users.PID
    where Users.UID= @LID
```

> Controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int S)
    {
           SLMEntitiesDB dbContext = new SLMEntitiesDB();
           List<User> UList = dbContext.Users.Where(U => U.LID == S).ToList();

            return View(UList);

        }
```

> How I can display it in a way or another

Answer (score 0):

Check out answer here: [Display List in a View MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958119/display-list-in-a-view-mvc)

The solution is simple, you need to use the Model inside the view and create a razor template accordingly.

```
@model IEnumerable<UList>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Title";
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        @item.Name
        <hr />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I agree, but that's when i want to display the data from one table.

Comment: here, i need to add an attribute from another table that's why i created a function to do that and i need to store / display this function into a list

Comment: @MomenAlnaser the stored procedure of yours returns a list that has properties from 2 tables. I'd suggest you to express yourself properly, because the answer itself is bad, you wan't to display a result of a sql call as a table on a mvc view. Also would note that you don't need to create a stored procedure, function or view to join 2 tables, as entity framework can that handle directly: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/linq-to-entities/join-query-entity-framework/

Comment: I'm sorry but im still new in this, Now I have below list and it's working fine, how can I then join another attribute from another table

Comment: please check the controller

Answer (score 0):

So, your controller does not uses the SQL you have created. I'd suggest to do check out these 2 links:

1. http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Left-Outer-Joins-in-LINQ-with-Entity-Framework
2. https://www.tektutorialshub.com/linq-to-entities/join-query-entity-framework/

**I'd do it probably his way:**

```
var modelQuery =
  from u in Users
  from p in Products.Where(p => p.PID == u.PID).DefaultIfEmpty() **// NOTE: this does not seems to bee a good relation, I'd assume a NxN relation with a ternary table, but this is what you got in your SQL**
  select new {
    UserName = u.UserName,
    PName = p.PName
  };

var model = modelQuery.ToList(); // NOTE: in debugger you can examine the select that is described via the modelQuery and you also do not need to execute the query here, as returning modelQuery for the view is also an option.
```

**I'd suggest you to:**

1. check out Northwind database (user/products/catalogs) - a very good sample DB free to download from Microsoft
2. Learn basics of relational databases, like the N:1, 1:N, N:N (and 1:1) relations
3. Post your DB diagram here (without the whole question is just a mess)
4. And explicitly whether you want to use the SQL procedure in the controller or you just want a way to display information from 2 tables joined